Here i want to serialize and deserialize the Tree struct but the not able to do
This error comes in the picture :- the trait bound MerkleTree: BorshSerialize is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait BorshSerialize:
bool
i8
i16
i32
i64
i128
usize
u8
and 110 others
see issue #48214
Here is the code :-
use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    merkletreers::{tree::MerkleTree, utils::hash_it},
    solana_program::{entrypoint::ProgramResult, msg, program_error::ProgramError},
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct WhitelistArgs {
    pub accounts: Vec<String>,
}

const ADMIN_ACCOUNT: &str = "Cv66dQwcSJDdXNVHybchYqp73d75Y8XWj6pKcjN3ffAy";

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct Tree {
    pub merkle_tree: MerkleTree,
}

pub(crate) static mut WHITELIST_TREE: Option<Tree> = None;

pub fn whitelist_account(args: WhitelistArgs, admin_account: String) -> ProgramResult {
    if admin_account != ADMIN_ACCOUNT {
        return Err(ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
    }

    let leaves: Vec<[u8; 32]> = args
        .accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|account_str| {
            let account_bytes = account_str.as_bytes();
            let mut buffer = [0u8; 32];
            hash_it(account_bytes, &mut buffer);
            buffer
        })
        .collect();

    let whitelist_tree = MerkleTree::new(leaves);

    let tree = Tree {
        merkle_tree: whitelist_tree,
    };

    msg!("Accounts have been added to the whitelist");
    msg!("{:?}", tree.merkle_tree.root);

    unsafe {
        WHITELIST_TREE = Some(tree);
    }

    Ok(())
}


The MerkleTree in your Tree struct also needs to implement the BorshSerialize and BorshDeserialize traits in order to work.
You may need to create a new struct that can convert between the external MerkleTree and your own merkle tree, and then have that new struct derive the BorshSerialize / BorshDeserialize traits.
